# AWS to local network integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, nat

I want to access my local network servers from amazon instances. I cant use amazon direct connect as a solution for this. Anybody can suggest a solution for this.

Comment: If you expect a helpful recommendation you should explicitly state why you cannot use amazon direct connect because this will very likely also limit the alternative options. In any case this isn't really programming related and should be asked with **more details** on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways in which you can access your on-prem network servers from AWS.

1. The straight forward way is to have your On-Prem servers attached to Public Accessible IP. [ this wouldn't be appropriate for most of the use cases - considering the security / access stand points ]
2. Have a VPN setup in your local network / servers and link it up to AWS VPC with [Virtual Private Gateway Connection initiated / established](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html).
3. The other way is to have a DX - Direct Connect Setup. The key difference between Point [2](http://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) with this is that; when you use [Direct Connect](http://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) - there is a secure, dedicated, isolated network line running from your office to AWS ( provided by 3rd Party / AWS Partners )

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a VPC in AWS and create an VPN gateway.  Then use routing to direct traffic on your local office ip address range to point towards your vpn gateway.